# rename files& directories {searchstr} with {replacestr}

Tags: perl, cygwin, batch-processing

I have an application (Templify) that creates a templatized directory structure, but it seems to not be able to rename the "__NAME__" with what I've identified as the target.

This is fine if I can find a clean way to rename all files & directories with my replacement text.

I found a rename.pl method that renames files, and I found some code that removes underscores in file names and replaces it with spaces... but when I modify the code to put in my search terms, it never seems to work.

So, basically, I need to replace "__NAME__" with something like "Project-Name".

I'm happy to modify the search strings for each future reuse, but I'd love to figure out how to create a file to which I can pass ARGS.

I'm on XP and can use cygwin (cygwin doesn't seem to have 'rename' which makes it hard to locate linux-type solutions with using the function called 'rename'....)

I did find [this](http://www.mattweber.org/2007/03/04/python-script-renamepy/) which is easy to use for files in the current directory, but I don't know enough to tell it to recurse into sub-directories.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: When you say "it never seems to work", I'd love to see the code you tried.  Did you get an error?  Or was it just that nothing happened?  Can you share a before-and-after directory listing?

Comment: I just meant that the application I was using asked me for a project name, and the value I entered was never used in the newly created directories.  I assumed that the directories & files with "__NAME__" in them was supposed to be replaced with what I'd entered as my project name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From cygwin:

```
find /cygdrive/c/mytree -type f | perl -ne 'rename $_, $1/Project-Name if m[^(.*)/__NAME__$]'
```

Or using python:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\mytree"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename == "__NAME__":
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(root, "Project-Name"))
```

Comment: thanks, but I got an error on the cygwin version:  Missing comma after first argument to rename function at -e line 1, near "Name if".  Where should I place this comma?  Thx.

Comment: Better add quotes: `rename $_, "$1/Project-Name"`